# Form Handing in Angular Using Reactive Programming

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I wanted to know, what is the angular way to handle form like below where formcontrol number is not fix. eg.

```
<ngForm #formData onsubmit="getEditedData(formData)">
  <textarea
        class="elm-textarea "
        placeholder="Name"
        maxlength="200"
        [value]="questionAnsData.id"
      ></textarea>
      <div *ngFor="let question of questionAnsData.questions; let i = index">
        <label class="label">Question {{ i + 1 }}</label>
        <textarea
          class="elm-textarea "
          placeholder="Question {{ i + 1 }}"
          maxlength="200"
          [value]="question"
        ></textarea>
      </div>
      <div *ngFor="let answer of questionAnsData.answers; let j = index">
        <label class="label">Answer {{ j + 1 }}</label>
        <textarea
          class="elm-textarea "
          placeholder="Answer {{ j + 1 }}"
          maxlength="200"
          [value]="answer"
        ></textarea>
      </div>
</ngForm>
```

My Data set is -

```
questionAnsData = [{
    id: "set1",
    questions: ["Hello, how are you?", "Hi, how are you?", ", how are you?" ],
    answers: ["Good", "I am good"]
  }];
```

[Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3fh8ze?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)
THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Answer (score 0):

you can use FormArray from reactive forms and push there any count of controls you need
article with [example](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/nested-formarray-example-add-form-fields-dynamically/)